# One bitmap for multiple images...same memory?

Tags: android

If I use the same bitmap for 2 or 3 image views. Does it mean that I am occupying 3 times the bitmap size in the memory? or is it counted as one bitmap?

I am looking to see if I do Bitmap with with tiling, as oppose to ready made image, would it save lots of memory.

Thanks

Comment: how many times do you load the bitmap?

Comment: What do you mean by "load"? like setting the image view to the bitmap or actually decoding the file to be loaded in a bitmap variable

Comment: well I decode the file once and use the same variable for both images... What about tile mode of background